# Getting an Error-404 from my web-host provider. Website converts YouTube to mp3

Tags: javascript, webserver

I am trying to re-create a tutorial I found which converts YouTube to mp3. The problem is when I use the website I get sent to a Error-404 page. I made my website using Freednom to get a free domain name and AwardSpace to get a web-hosting service. My websites name is Simplemp3.ga. When I post the video link I want to convert I get transferred to an Error-404 page. Not sure if it has something to do with the domain name service or the web-hosting service (since they are both free). Maybe there is some limitations preventing the download of YouTube to mp3 with the limited servers and databases?

The way I tried changing the code was from Local host 4000 to the website itself: simplemp3.ga. At first I got a hosting problem when it was directed to my localhost 4000. Then I changed it to simplemp3.ga and I got the Error-404 page from AwardSpace.

Here is the code I changed (JavaScript):

```
var convertBtn = document.querySelector('.convert-button');
var URLinput = document.querySelector('.URL-input');
convertBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`URL: ${URLinput.value}`);
    sendURL(URLinput.value);
});
function sendURL(URL) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/download?URL=${URL}`, {
        method:'GET'
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

To:

```
var convertBtn = document.querySelector('.convert-button');
var URLinput = document.querySelector('.URL-input');
convertBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`URL: ${URLinput.value}`);
    sendURL(URLinput.value);
});
function sendURL(URL) {
    window.location.href = `simplemp3.ga/download?URL=${URL}`;
}
```

After this point I got the Error-404 page from AwardSpace.

Here is the complete code tutorial:

https://blog.usejournal.com/how-i-made-my-own-youtube-downloader-using-javascript-and-node-js-160b172f6e10

Please, any and all help are greatly appreciated!

Thank you